# Copy between Elastices | REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to copy indexes between AWS Opensearch(Elastic engine v6.8) to AWS Opensearch (Opensearch engine v2.3).

I'm using elasticdump to copy the indexes.

I got the foloowing error while in one of the indexes:

`Error Emitted => {"Message":"Request size exceeded 104857600 bytes"}`

`dump ended with error (get phase) => REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE: {"Message":"Request size exceeded 104857600 bytes"}`

I read that in AWS Opensearch it's limit to 100MB per wrrting to the Opensearch.

I tried to reduce the limit to 10 (using --limit) and still failed at the same point.
Only when I set the limit to 1 it's works.

the question if someone can help me to understand if there is any parameter that I missing or I need a combination of parameters to get it works.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's weird because elasticdump usually handles pretty well the read/write sequencing, I've been using it to replicate multi-TB indexes without any issues. Do you have really large documents in your index?

Comment: Hey @val
yes - I also have multi indexes that total amount is 20TB...

edit: the issue is that the AWS is limiting the write to 100MB per operation/batch and the default of --limit is 100 docs per operation, the elasticdump is not split the batch if it's more than 100MB

Comment: How big is your biggest document?